# MPI-2 file format options

Tags: file-io, parallel-processing

I am trying to speed up my file I/O using MPI-2, but there doesn't appear to be any way to read/write formatted files. Many of my I/O files are formatted for ease of pre and post-processing.

Any suggestions for an MPI-2 solution for formatted I/O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual answer to using MPI-IO while generating some sort of portable, sensible file format is to use [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) or [NetCDF4](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/) .   There's a real learning curve to both (but also lots of [tutorials](https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/a/af/Netcdfhdf5.pdf) out there) but the result is you hve portable, self-describing files that there are a zillion tools for accessing, manipulating, etc.

If by `formatted' output you mean plain human-readable text, then as someone who does a lot of this stuff, I wouldn't be doing my job if I didn't urge you enough to start moving away from that approach.   We all by and large start that way, dumping plain text so we can quickly see what's going on; but it's just not a good approach for doing production runs.   The files are bloated, the I/O is *way* slower (I routinely see 6x slowdown in using ascii as vs binary, partly because you're writing out small chunks at a time and partly because of the string conversions), and for what?   If there's so little data being output that you actually *can* feasibly read and understand the output, you don't need parallel I/O; if there are so many numbers that you can't really plausibly flip through them all and understand what's going on, then what's the point?

Comment: +1: especially for your words about moving away from human-readable files.

Comment: My program input files are human readable since humans write them. Can MPI-2 read them in in parallel?
My program outputs are not human readable (like you say, why bother when no one will ever check a 2G file word by word), but they are formatted to be read in by visualization software. I must stay true to that format.

Comment: +1 For suggesting HDF5 library (note that HDF5 is **not** a file format but is a library for writing files. The HDF5 standard says nothing about what data is stored in a particular file.